# Hibernate GeneratedValue using GenericGenerator is ignored

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

This field "auftragsnummer" always stays null, even though it is annotated with @GeneratedValue:

```
@Entity
public class Auftrag implements Serializable
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   @Pattern(regexp = AUFTRAGSNUMMER_REGEXP, message = "{validator.auftragsnummer}")
   @Length(min = 20, max = 20)
   @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_auftragsnummer", strategy = "de.software.AuftragsnummerGenerator")
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_auftragsnummer")
   @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
   private String auftragsnummer;
}
```

I store it using `getHibernateTemplate().persist(t)`. The referenced generator class implements `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator`.
I have no idea why it is ignored.

Environment:

- Hibernate 5.0.1
- Spring 4.2.1
- Java 7
- DB2 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA only mandates support for `@GeneratedValue` on `@Id` fields.

If your order number doesn't depend on the entity's primary key, then the easiest solution is to use `@PrePersist` e.g.

```
@PrePersist
public void onCreate() {
    auftragsnummer = ...;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out!

Comment: It works, but due to legacy code it couldn't yet switch to it - but we definitely should. Marking your answer as correct.